Lettre Rust hangs at 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<CRLF> in Docker
I'm implementing an email service with Rust using Lettre, but when I run the program in Docker, it hangs at:
DEBUG lettre::transport::smtp::client::async_connection: << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<CRLF> 

When I run it on my host machine, the process successfully passes this message and reaches the following debug log:
DEBUG lettre::transport::smtp::client::async_connection: connection encrypted

However, in Docker, it doesn't progress beyond this point. What could be the issue?
code
impl Mailer {
    pub fn default_smtp_suporte() -> Self {
        let envs = Env::get_environment();

        let creds = Credentials::new(
            envs.email_address.to_string(),
            envs.email_password.to_string(),
        );

        let mailer: AsyncSmtpTransport<Tokio1Executor> =
            AsyncSmtpTransport::<Tokio1Executor>::starttls_relay("smtp.gmail.com")
                .unwrap()
                .timeout(Some(Duration::from_secs(8)))
                .credentials(creds)
                .build();

        Self {
            async_mailer: mailer,
            email: envs.email_address,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_message_builder(&self) -> Result<MessageBuilder, Box<dyn Error>> {
        Ok(Message::builder().from(self.email.clone().parse()?))
    }

    pub async fn send(&self, email: Message) -> Result<(), String> {
        // it hangs at this point
        let result = self.async_mailer.send(email).await;

        if result.is_err() {
            return Err(result.unwrap_err().to_string());
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

Dockerfile
FROM rust:1.83 AS base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    openssl \
    tzdata \
    curl \
    telnet && \
    update-ca-certificates && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cargo install sccache --version 0.8.2
RUN cargo install cargo-chef --version 0.1.68

ENV RUSTC_WRAPPER=sccache SCCACHE_DIR=/sccache

FROM base AS planner

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$SCCACHE_DIR,sharing=locked \
    cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM base as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$SCCACHE_DIR,sharing=locked \
    cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json

COPY . .

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$SCCACHE_DIR,sharing=locked \
    cargo build --release

EXPOSE 465
EXPOSE 587

CMD ["cargo", "run", "--release"]

compose.yml
services:
  email_service:
    image: service/email_service
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: ./.env
    network_mode: host

